# FSCalender app crash when reload calender

Tags: ios, fscalendar

App crash when i reload my calendar in

```
- (void)calendar:(FSCalendar *)calendar didSelectDate:(NSDate *)date
```

method. it showing error :

```
- (void)calendar:(FSCalendar *)calendar didSelectDate:(NSDate *)date
```

MYCODE :

```
- (void)calendar:(FSCalendar *)calendar didSelectDate:(NSDate *)date{

    int i = 0;
    EventDate *obj = [[EventDate alloc] init];

    for (EventDate *event in selectedDates) {
        if (([gregorian component:NSCalendarUnitDay fromDate:date] == [gregorian component:NSCalendarUnitDay fromDate:event.eventDate]) &&
            ([gregorian component:NSCalendarUnitMonth fromDate:date] == [gregorian component:NSCalendarUnitMonth fromDate:event.eventDate])&&
            ([gregorian component:NSCalendarUnitYear fromDate:date] == [gregorian component:NSCalendarUnitYear fromDate:event.eventDate]) ) {

            [obj initEventDateWith:date andWithRole:[self getRole:event] andWithBgColor:[self getColor:event]];

            [selectedDates removeObjectAtIndex:i];
            [selectedDates addObject:obj];
            break;
        }i++;
     }     
}
```

app crash  on this method :

```
    - (void)reloadDataForCell:(FSCalendarCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    cell.calendar = self; // here my app crash


}
```

Comment: share inside code for  reloadDataForCell .

Comment: i tried but same issue.. :(  i reload calendar after for in loop

Comment: share your code here which are inside reloadDataForCell and related code.

Comment: any error log ?

Comment: 2017-05-05 10:10:58.378 corppool[717:13874] date :2017-05-04 18:30:00 +0000
2017-05-05 10:13:04.562 corppool[717:13874] -[FSCalendarBlankCell setCalendar:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fc88bd16420
2017-05-05 10:13:08.013 corppool[717:13874] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[FSCalendarBlankCell setCalendar:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fc88bd16420'
*** First throw call stack: